# Selecting row values as column in an oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table:

```
select * from ABCD;

|    ABCD_ID | ROLE  | NAME | PARAM   | VALUE |
+============+=======+======+=========+=======+
|    1       | Allow | A1   | Period1 | 1     |
|    1       | Allow | A1   | Period1 | 2     |
|    1       | Allow | A1   | Period1 | 3     |
|    2       | Allow | A2   | Period2 | 11    |
|    2       | Allow | A2   | Period2 | 12    |
|    3       | Allow | A3   | Period3 | 111   |
|    4       | Allow | A4   | XY      | 200   |
```

I want to run select query to have period as column and values of the column will be "VALUE"

Output required:

```
|    ABCD_ID   | ROLE  | NAME | Period |
+==============+=======+======+========+
|            1 | Allow | A1   | 1      |
|            1 | Allow | A1   | 2      |
|            1 | Allow | A1   | 3      |
|            2 | Allow | A2   | 11     |
|            2 | Allow | A2   | 12     |
|            3 | Allow | A3   | 111    |
```

Query I tried:

```
select ABCD_ID,role,name,param, 
       (select distinct value 
        from ABCD 
        where ABCD_ID=a.ABCD_ID 
          and param like '%Period%') as "Period" 
from ABCD a 
where role='Allow' 
  and param like '%Period%'
```

Getting this error:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Your expected output looks to me to be almost identical to the starting table.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I have column param in ABCD table where it's distinct values are Period1, Period2, Period3 and XY. I want to have Period( which will have all period and not XY) as a column which will give me its values for distinct ABCD_ID. I hope i am able to explain it properly.

Comment: No, it is still very unclear to me.  Maybe edit your question and use sample data which reveals the distinct quality to what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple column alias to me:

```
select ABCD_ID,
       role,
       name,
       value as "Period"
from ABCD a 
where role='Allow' 
  and param like 'Period%'
```

Comment: Sorry... I have to rephrase the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add in the condition of 'role ='Allow'.

Select ABCD_ID,
       role,
       name,
       value as "Period"
from ABCD a 
where param like 'Period%'

Comment: Sorry...i have rephrase the question